# Creating a date variable based on a specified row interval

Tags: python, pandas

How do I create an additional `Date` column with the following specifications:

- Starts at 1 January 2020
- `Date` increases by 1 day, every 125 rows

The actual dataset is much larger than this, so `Date` may cover multiple years.

```
RandomNumberList = np.random.randint(1,10,250)
pd.DataFrame(RandomNumberList, columns = ["Value"])
```

Comment: What is expected last value of `Date` column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If need repeat each date 125 times:**

General solution for any length of DataFrame with [`date_range`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html) with [`Index.repeat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.repeat.html) with add `1` value if not divisible length:

```
N = 125
r = pd.date_range('2020-01-01', periods=len(df) // N + 1)

df['Date'] = r.repeat(N)[:len(df)]
```

If length of df is divisible by `125` solution should be simplify:

```
r = pd.date_range('2020-01-01', periods=len(df) // 125)

df['Date'] = r.repeat(125)
```

---

```
print (df)
     Value       Date
0        4 2020-01-01
1        7 2020-01-01
2        9 2020-01-01
3        1 2020-01-01
4        3 2020-01-01
..     ...        ...
245      3 2020-01-02
246      8 2020-01-02
247      8 2020-01-02
248      5 2020-01-02
249      6 2020-01-02

[250 rows x 2 columns]
```

---

**If need repeat 125 datetimes:**

```
N = 125
r = pd.date_range('2020-01-01', periods=N)


df['Date'] = np.tile(r, len(df) // N + 1)[:len(df)]
print (df)
     Value       Date
0        9 2020-01-01
1        2 2020-01-02
2        1 2020-01-03
3        2 2020-01-04
4        8 2020-01-05
..     ...        ...
245      2 2020-04-30
246      6 2020-05-01
247      3 2020-05-02
248      8 2020-05-03
249      9 2020-05-04

[250 rows x 2 columns]
```

Answer (score 1):

If You want a thorough knowledge, read the answer written by jezrael.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame as df

RandomNumberList = np.random.randint(1,10,250)
df = pd.DataFrame(RandomNumberList, columns = ["Value"])

df['Date'] = np.repeat(pd.date_range('2020-01-01', periods=2), 125)
print(df)

"""
     Value       Date
0        7 2020-01-01
1        1 2020-01-01
2        5 2020-01-01
3        3 2020-01-01
4        4 2020-01-01
..     ...        ...
245      6 2020-01-02
246      9 2020-01-02
247      7 2020-01-02
248      7 2020-01-02
249      8 2020-01-02

[250 rows x 2 columns]

"""
```